# How to integrate and use a remote MySQL database in a WPF application

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, networking

I'm currently trying to understand how to program a personal project that will use MySQL for the database and WPF C# for the local client. Basically, it will be a store of applications (pretty much in the same style as google play) that will require a login and then give the choice of an application to install to the user. The bit that puzzle me is how i'm going to :

- Allow the application to be installed on the system and be launched **without** the need to install mysql beforehand.
- Access the MySQL database itself. It's fairly easy if it's a local database, but how does one manage a remote MySQL database? Another question related to that matter, will i have to hardcode my MySQL name and password in the application itself? If so, won't it create a security hole in my application if someone is able to get access to it? (This is what you do in php i believe, but the thing is, php is server side, so in theory the user will never be able to get the php code without ftp access. Since i run my application locally, anybody could obfuscate the code and get those information, isn't it?)

Also, could somebody point out a good MySQL database host (free or not)? Maybe i haven't searched for the right thing, but i couldn't find any host that provide "only" a MySQL database.

In any case, can anybody give me some light on the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you should think about a different architecture:

- MySQL database [server]
  This server holds you data etc.
- WebService (SOAP or REST) [server]
  This is the only piece of software accessing the MySQL database. Ideally this only reachable via SSL (HTTPS).
- WPF client [client]
  The client does NOT communicate with MySQL directly but only through WebService.

As for how to secure credentials you have some options:

- ask the user for a password which you then transmit to WebService...
- use one "client-certificate" per user (this allows to revoke access from server-side without changing the client)

Comment: I understand what should be the WebService, but i'm not sure how to implement it. By searching on the net, it would seems that it's another application running and exchanging information with the local application (like you said). Does that mean that i actually need a VPS or dedicated server in order to run that said WebService 24/24? I'm sorry if that sound trivial.

Comment: @zaedas99 yes, it is an "application" (for example an ASP.NET WebAPI) and it needs some WebServer (like VPS or dedicated server) to run... best case is you run both (MySQL and WebService) on the same machine and configure MySQL to only accept "local connections".

Comment: Okay, that's what i thought. Thanks a lot for the help and the clarification.